# Scroll back to top link is visible on first load

Tags: javascript, css

Hi all I'm trying to make this scroll-to-top link work.

The main code works but the link is visible when the page initially loads. [Here](http://www.nov11.asia/) is a link so you can understand what I mean.

Javascript

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.backtop').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.backtop').fadeOut();
  }
})
```

CSS

```
.backtop{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to start with a css property that hides it

```
.backtop{
  display: none; /* add this */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 5%;
}
```

There are also some pretty bad performance problems with your code as well:

**A `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` is called for every scroll event**, whether it's needed or not. Try something like this:

```
var isHidden = true;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var newScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (newScrollTop > 800 && isHidden) {
        $(".backtop").fadeIn();
        isHidden = false;
    }
    else if (newScrollTop <= 800 && !isHidden) {
        $(".backtop").fadeOut();
        isHidden = true;
    }
});
```

By monitoring the state of your button, you can call the fade commands only when it's necessary.

**The scroll event has inconsistent behavior** across platforms and fires sporadically.

With browser support improving for `requestAnimationFrame`, it's much better to monitor the scroll position with that. Instead of waiting for scroll events, when the browser is rendering the frames, you can just check if the scroll position has changed. If it has, show or hide your button.

```
var scroll = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
    myToTopLogicFunction();
};
```